# MVC design pattern - who loads view initially

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns

This query is about MVC design pattern in general and not ASP.net MVC framework

I understand in MVC (desktop application):

1. User clicks something in view
2. this is passed on to controller to manage
3. controller makes some changes in Model
4. Model calls method on view which has the logic to refresh UI

Questions around these:

**Q1)** Can controller also modify View or Model only updates View?

**Q2)** When screen loads for the first time, there is no Model change. Then, who fetches data from model and populates view? View directly calls Model and populates itself OR controller gets data and passes to view method OR some dummy event is raised at Model which updates View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) :

1. The user interacts with the user interface in some way. (for example, presses a mouse button).
2. The controller handles the input event from the user interface, often via a registered handler or callback and converts the event into appropriate user action, understandable for the model.
3. The controller notifies the model of the user action, possibly resulting in a change in the model's state. (For example, the controller updates the user's shopping cart.)
4. **A view queries the model in order to generate an appropriate user interface (for example, the view lists the shopping cart's contents). The view gets its own data from the model. In some implementations, the controller may issue a general instruction to the view to render itself. In others, the view is automatically notified by the model of changes in state (Observer) that require a screen update.**
5. The user interface waits for further user interactions, which restarts the control flow cycle.

Comment: Actually my source of putting this question is the point 4. only in wikipedia definition. If I go with this statement, View can directly call model method to populate itself. But wouldn't that be making model less streamlined?

Comment: @enableDeepak: i don't realy understand you're question about model geting less streamlined but anyways please check this image http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/images/mvc-structure-generic.gif it explains it better than words on how MVC should actualy be implemented .

Comment: As shown in Diagram, View can directly request for data from Model (bypassing controller). Does it mean In View.cs I can write something like Model.GetData()? This actually is all I want to know. If this is correct, then my thread question actually gets answered as View will call Model directly to get initial values.

Comment: @enableDeepak: yes you can call Model.GetData() in you're View file, however you shouldn't call Model.ChangeData() from you're view as that is the job of the controller.

Comment: One more question... Can controller also directly call view methods()? If there is a view to add data, is it fine to say that validation will be performed at controller level. If validation fails, it can directly call view's method (say ShowError)?

Comment: Yes, it's the controllers job to to "select" the apropiate view to be executed/rendered. So say user whants to save a picture, the action is cought by the view and passed to the controller, controller tells the model it has to save the picture, model realises user doesn't have permissions and returns false to the controller, then the controller needs to change the current view. The model tough can notify the view if data has changed but it shouldn't be allowed to acutaly change the view .

Comment: I would focus less on the _what_ and focus on the why. Your goal is to have a view that knows about the controller and model (preferably only the abstract/interface) but the controller and model know nothing about the view. So that way you can use any type of view (console, windows, unix, webservice, mobile)

Answer (score 0):

In the web context, you always have a request from a web browser. So the logic works as described above but there is a wrapper around it:

1. Browser sends request to server *and waits for reply*
2. The four steps above. In this case, the UI is also an internal model in the server.
3. The render engine creates a new UI (a new HTML page) from the internal UI model
4. The server sends the new HTML document back to the browser
5. Browser renders result